Video Wont Play in Github Servers - Playwright JS
I have some automation using Playwright Node where I need the video to load/play. I read that the typical Chromium does not have the right media codec to play a video so you need real Chrome. I changed my playwright config to now pull the executable path for real Chrome and got it all working locally but when I run it in Github Servers for a pipeline, it isn't working. I am using a mac server in Github macos-latest-xlarge

I tried various installation tactics in my github YML:
- run: |
   npx playwright install
   npx playwright install chrome

- run: |
   PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=$HOME/pw-browsers npx playwright install
   npx playwright install chrome

Also tried a setup-chrome github actions
- uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@v1
- run: chrome --version

Here is my full YML:
name: Run Automation On Demand

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      URL:
        description: 'Which dashboard url do you want to run this on?'
        required: true
        default: 'xxxx'
      APIURL:
        description: 'Which API url do you want to run this on?'
        required: true
        default: 'xxxx'
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Which suite do you want to run?
        options:
        - ' '
        - All Tests
        - All UI
        - All API
        - APIKeys
        - Auth
        - BotLibrary
        - Bots
        - Config
        - CustomFields
        - DELETE
        - Export
        - Filter
        - FNOL
        - GET
        - HIL
        - HumanInTheLoop
        - Impersonate
        - InspectionAnalyst
        - Login
        - Notes
        - OrganizationGroups
        - Organizations
        - PATCH
        - pin
        - POST
        - ReportDetails
        - Reports
        - Roles
        - Search
        - 'SystemAdministrator'
        - Upload
      DeleteOldData:
        description: 'Clean automation organization in the stage env? (DO NOT CHECK IF: Automation is being ran by PRs or on-demand)'
        type: boolean
        required: false
        default: false

jobs:
  job-delete-data:

    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.DeleteOldData == 'true' }}
    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.7.3]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - run: npx playwright install chromium
    - name: GCP Authentication
      id: GCPAuth
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
      with:
        project_id: 'xxxx'
        service_account: 'xxxxxx'
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.KEY_PIPELINE_JSON }}'
    - name: If Prod URL, Cannot Run
      if: ${{contains(github.event.inputs.URL, 'xxxx') }}
      run: |
        echo "Cannot run on Prod currently"
        exit 1
    - name: Delete old data
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.DeleteOldData == 'true' }}
      run: npx playwright test delete.teardown.spec.ts

  job-run-all:
    if: ${{ always() && github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }}
    needs: job-delete-data
    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.7.3]
        automation-type: [{"name": "UI", "command": "URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test playwright/dashboard --workers=8"}, {"name": "API", "command": "npx playwright test playwright/api --workers=20"}]
      fail-fast: false

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - run: |
        npx playwright install
        npx playwright install chrome
    - name: GCP Authentication
      id: GCPAuth
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
      with:
        project_id: 'xxxx'
        service_account: 'xxxxx'
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.KEY_PIPELINE_JSON }}'
    - name: If Prod URL, Cannot Run
      if: ${{contains(github.event.inputs.URL, 'xxxxx') }}
      run: |
        echo "Cannot run on Prod currently"
        exit 1
    - name: If All Tests, Run All Playwright Tests in Parallel
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All Tests' }}
      run: ${{ matrix.automation-type.command }}
    - name: Run Slack Notification
      if: always()
      uses: ravsamhq/notify-slack-action@v2
      with:
        status: ${{ job.status }} # required
        notify_when: 'failure'
        message_format: '{emoji} {workflow} {status_message} | <{run_url}|View Failed Run From Stage>'
      env:
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: '${{secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK}}'
    - name: Upload report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: playwright-report-${{matrix.automation-type.name}}
        path: 'playwright-report/'
        retention-days: 30
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: failed-videos
        path: test-results/**/video.webm
        retention-days: 30

  job-run-suite:
    needs: job-delete-data
    if: ${{ always() && github.event.inputs.choice != 'All Tests' }}

    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [21.7.3]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - run: |
        PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=$HOME/pw-browsers npx playwright install
        npx playwright install chrome
    - name: GCP Authentication
      id: GCPAuth
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
      with:
        project_id: 'xxxx'
        service_account: 'xxxxx'
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.KEY_PIPELINE_JSON }}'
    - name: If Prod URL, Cannot Run
      if: ${{contains(github.event.inputs.URL, 'xxxx') }}
      run: |
        echo "Cannot run on Prod currently"
        exit 1
    - name: If DEV URL, Can Only Run APIS
      if: ${{contains(github.event.inputs.URL, 'xxxx') && github.event.inputs.choice != 'All API' }}
      run: |
        echo "Cannot run on DEV on anything besides APIs, you inputted ${{github.event.inputs.choice}}"
        exit 1
    - name: If Suite Specific, Run Just Selected Suite
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice != 'All Tests' && github.event.inputs.choice != 'All UI' && github.event.inputs.choice != 'All API' && github.event.inputs.choice != ' ' }}
      run: URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test --workers=8 --grep @${{ github.event.inputs.choice }}
    - name: If All UI, Run All Playwright UI Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All UI' }}
      run: URL=${{ github.event.inputs.URL }} npx playwright test playwright/dashboard --workers=8
    - name: If All API, Run All Playwright API Tests
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.choice == 'All API' }}
      run: APIURL=${{ github.event.inputs.APIURL }} npx playwright test playwright/api --workers=20
    - name: Upload report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: playwright-report
        path: 'playwright-report/'
        retention-days: 30
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: failed-videos
        path: test-results/**/video.webm
        retention-days: 30

And nothing seems to work. What can I do?
